# Adding multiple properties into nested JSON array

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, uwp, json.net

I've done a lot of searching at it appears there is no article for this specific case.

I have some JSON (Note that it is a JArray, and not a JObject)

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Name 1",
    "Icon": "Icon 1",
    "Samples": [
      {
        "Name": "Sample 1",
      },
      {
        "Name": "Sample 2",
      },
      {
        "Name": "Sample 3",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Name 2",
    "Icon": "Icon 2",
    "Samples": [
      {
        "Name": "Sample 1",
      },
      {
        "Name": "Sample 2",
      },
      {
        "Name": "Sample 3",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Name 3",
    "Icon": "Icon 3",
    "Samples": [
      {
        "Name": "Sample 1",
      },
      {
        "Name": "Sample 2",
      },
      {
        "Name": "Sample 3",
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

So this has 3 levels. The root, which contains the "SampleCategories". The "SampleCategories" which contains some items and a "Samples" list, and the "Samples" list which contains many objects.

So, what I'm essentially trying to do here is to add an object into the Samples list, inside a specific SampleCategory. So for example:

I want to add "Sample 4" to the Samples array in "Name 1" so it looks like this:

```
  {
    "Name": "Name 1",
    "Icon": "Icon 1",
    "Samples": [
      {
        "Name": "Sample 1",
      },
      {
        "Name": "Sample 2",
      },
      {
        "Name": "Sample 3",
      },
      {
        "Name": "Sample 4",
      }
    ]
  },
```

I thought this would be fairly easy when I started out but it turns out there are lots of roadblocks that I can't seem to get my head around.

So I have two models for each level, "SampleCategory" for the top level that has the Name, Icon and Samples, which goes off to another model called "Samples[]"

So I'm afraid I'm at an embarrassing point in this process... Right at the start. I've de-serialised the json, and done some bits around finding my chosen SampleCategory, and created an object ready to add in, and that's as far as I've gotten...

```
var categories = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SampleCategory>>(json);
var applications = categories.Find(c => c.Name.Equals("Name 1"));

var sample = new Sample
{
    Name = "Sample 4",
};
```

I don't appear to be able to find any way of adding a new 'sample' into the Samples list of a chosen SampleCategory. I even tried adding to the object path *directly*, the path of which I got using this:

```
JObject jo = jsonArray.Children<JObject>().FirstOrDefault(o => o["Name"] != null && o["Name"].ToString() == "Name 1");
```

But there doesn't appear to be a way to add to an array as I guess it's a static length?

What is best practice modifying JSON like this?

Documentation (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm) suggests there a few ways to do it when playing around with JObjects, but it doesn't suggest a way to do it with nested objects inside of JArrays.

Can anyone help or suggest some methods to do this? I'm sure it's probably simple, but I'm going through a loop trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your model looks something like this:

```
public class Sample
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SampleCategory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public List<Sample> Samples { get; set; }
}
```

If you are not sure how a model must look like to match a given json string you can make use of a tool like [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) which will generate the model for you.

To be able to add a new sample to a specific category you can find the specific category using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq) after deserializing it:

```
var categories = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SampleCategory>>(json);
var category = categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Name 1");
```

Now (if a category with the name exists) just add the new sample to the list:

```
if(category != null)
{
    category.Samples.Add(new Sample{Name = "Sample 4"});
}
```

To serialize it back to json:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(categories);
```

**Edit**
If you cannot switch your model type for `Samples` to `List<T>` and you don't want to convert the array temporarily to `List<T>`, you can do something like this:

```
if(category != null)
{
    category.Samples = category.Samples.Concat(new Sample[]{new Sample{Name = "Sample 4"}}).ToArray();
}
```

If you are not bothered by an additional `List<T>` cast another approach would be:

```
if(category != null)
{
    var tmpList = category.Samples.ToList();
    tmpList.Add(new Sample{Name = "Sample 4"});
    category.Samples = tmpList.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This is achingly close to what I need, but I think there is one missing step. Firstly, you got my model spot on, but in SampleCategory there is a small change. It's public Sample[] Samples {get; set;} And then I get an error message saying Sample[] does not contain a definition for add. Which I guess makes sense, but is there any way to do it for sample[] rather than a public list?

Comment: Doesn't seem to like the concat. Cannot implicitly convert type collections.generic.iEnumerable to sample[].

I'm completely open to temporarily converting the array to a list. (after all, my end result should just be the json string I parsed in with a new sample, nothing too fancy) The only thing that cannot change is the model however, that needs to stay the same.

Comment: @Robbo My bad I forgot the `ToArray()` after `Concat()`. I updated my answer, works now.

Comment: You hero, figured there needed to be a toarray in there somewhere. Thanks very much for the help, this is now solved!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it could be as simple as :

```
applications.Samples.ToList().Add(sample);
```

I have no privilege to comment it :(

Comment: No dice, as Samples[] does not contain a definition for 'add'. And I believe c# arrays are immutable. By now I'm sure you can see the pickle I'm in. It seems like I'm going to have to do some crazy things with lists and such

Comment: well last shot :)) applications.Samples.ToList().Add(sample); you know. It depends on which type u used to define Samples in your model. if that is IEnumerable<Sample> you may have that problem.